# Close Azure Security Center Alerts automatically

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-automation, azure-security

Are there any way to close Azure security center alerts automatically? Like via a PowerShell script or something?

We are creating alerts in the new sentinel siem from security center, what we want is to close the cases on both, sentinel as well as security center.

For sentinel cases you can close automatically via logic apps, however the same feature on logic apps do no exist for Azure security center.

Regards,
Kelly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are closing the alerts for sentinel via logic apps,similarly Azure Security center uses security playbooks which are based on logic apps. For more information related to Security playbooks, please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/security-center-playbooks#what-is-security-playbook-in-security-center) article.